# Making a URL in a string usable by Ruby's Net::HTTP

Tags: ruby, url

Ruby's `Net:HTTP` needs to be given a full URL in order for it to connect to the server and get the file properly. By "full URL" I mean a URL including the `http://` part and the trailing slash if it needs it. For instance, `Net:HTTP` won't connect to a URL looking like this: `example.com`, but will connect just fine to `http://example.com/`. Is there any way to make sure a URL is a full URL, and add the required parts if it isn't?

**EDIT**: Here is the code I am using:

```
parsed_url = URI.parse(url)
req = Net::HTTP::Get.new(parsed_url.path)
res = Net::HTTP.start(parsed_url.host, parsed_url.port) {|http|
  http.request(req)
}
```

Comment: `Uri.parse` may be of help here.  http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/uri/rdoc/

Comment: @Brian: Odd, the URL is being parsed with `URI.parse`, and yet I'm getting errors when it's not given a proper URL.

Comment: Yes, URI.parse will give you a `URI::Generic` object instead of a `URI::HTTP` object if you exclude the HTTP. The `URI::Generic `class doesn't have a `request_uri` method, so Net::HTTP chokes on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would do a simple check for http/https:

```
if !(url =~ /^https?:/i)
  url = "http://" + url
end
```

This could be a more general one to handle multiple protocols (ftp, etc.)

```
if !(url =~ /^\w:/i)
  url = "http://" + url
end
```

In order to make sure `parsed_url.path` gives you a proper value (it should be `/` when no specific path was provided), you could do something like this:

```
req = Net::HTTP::Get.new(parsed_url.path.empty? ? '/' : parsed_url.path)
```

Comment: This works great. Although I still have the issue of the ending slash if the URL needs it.

Comment: @Mark: I don't think a trailing slash is required (just tested on Net::HTTP in Ruby 1.9)

Comment: Whenever I try it without the slash, I get the following error: /Users/mark/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-head/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:1660:in `initialize': HTTP request path is empty (ArgumentError)
 from /Users/mark/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-head/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:1779:in `initialize'
 from /Users/mark/Dropbox/prog/ruby/dl/lib/dl/dl.rb:9:in `new'
 from /Users/mark/Dropbox/prog/ruby/dl/lib/dl/dl.rb:9:in `download'
 from ./dl:40:in `<main>'

Comment: Can you update your question with the exact code you're using?

Comment: @Mark: See my updated answer. Note that when you just use `res = Net::HTTP.get(parsed_url)` you don't need to worry about the trailing slash.

Answer (score 3):

If this is only doing what the sample code shows, Open-URI would be an easier approach.

```
require 'open-uri'
res = open(url).read
```

Comment: Agreed. Once I started using it, I never looked back.

Comment: There are times Net::HTTP is required, because we need better control, but 99% of the time I'm using open-uri.